# Using `predict` in Keras to predict an 1D array in the same order as given

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am doing regression in Keras, with a neural network with 1 input, 10 hidden units and 1 output. I fit the model, as usual:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, nb_epoch=15, batch_size=32)
```

now I want to predict for a `xtest` that is (as `x_train` and `y_train`) a very big 1-dimensional numpy array. In the documentation of the Keras web, you can find:

```
predict(self, x, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
```

so I understand you have to do:

```
model.predict(xtest, batch_size=32)
```

I am confused by the `batch_size` instruction. Does it mean that `predict` takes the values of xtest in a random way?

Because what I need is that `predict` generates the outputs in **exactly** the same order as given by xtest. I mean, first of all the output predicted for xtest[0], then the output predicted for xtest[1], then the output predicted for xtest[2]... and so on. With that array predicted I want to do some comparisons with an actual ytest that I have and do some statistics. So, the order is essential. How can I do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The predict method preserves the order of examples. Batch size is essential when your data is big and you simply cannot load a lot of examples to your memory. Then it's loaded and evaluated batch by batch in order of original set.